# Accessing data outside of ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude I called in via ajax into their own variables so that I can use them in the request I'm going to make the the DarkSky API. I'm aware of them being local, and so can't be accessed outside of the ajax function, but I can't for the life of me work out a way around it. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //location API

  $("#myweather").load("window",function() {

    $("#location").fadeOut(function() {

      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(loc) {
          $("#location").html(loc.city)
          var long = loc.longitude
          var lat = loc.latitude
          }        
      });
    }).fadeIn();
  });      

      $("#result").load("location", function() {
        $("#result").fadeIn(function() {
          $.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/15f8bf5641489ec32f66662221933c14/" + lat + long, function(forecast) {
            consolelog(forecast);
          });
        });
      });
});
```

Comment: Your AJAX `success` function should call whatever code it is that loads `result`. Basically you want to be saying "get this thing from geoip, then use that to load this result".

Comment: why not turn the .load function into a $.fn.function and then call it in the success callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare these two variables outside the function like shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //location API
    var long = '';
    var lat = '';
  $("#myweather").load("window",function() {

    $("#location").fadeOut(function() {

      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(loc) {
          $("#location").html(loc.city)
          long = loc.longitude
          lat = loc.latitude
          }        
      });
    }).fadeIn();
  });      

      $("#result").load("location", function() {
        $("#result").fadeIn(function() {
          $.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/15f8bf5641489ec32f66662221933c14/" + lat + long, function(forecast) {
            consolelog(forecast);
          });
        });
      });
});
```

Comment: This only returns a ' ' in the console when i log it, as if its not being passed across?

Comment: It also depends upon where you are using console. Can I see that code ?

Comment: @EpicTriffid, I did not find console.log in the code with the above given link.

Comment: Sorry, try again!

Comment: But @EpicTriffid you are trying to console forecast variable. Not lat long. The question was about lat long variable not accessible. So my answer to your question is perfect. 
You may up vote and accept this answer. I am looking for your issue meanwhile.

Comment: @EpicTriffid, here is your solution for your 2nd query too:
Change your javascript code like this:
`function(forecast){
                $.each(forecast, function(i, field){
                    console.log(field);
                });
              });`

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyayit does work! Why though?

Comment: @EpicTriffid because it responds with JSON data, and you need to loop through JSON data to iterate each object.

Comment: @EpicTriffid hope my all efforts were helpful to you. :-)

Comment: @EpicTriffid, can you please accept the answer and vote it up !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //location API

  $("#myweather").load("window",function() {

    $("#location").fadeOut(function() {
      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(loc) {
          $("#location").html(loc.city)
          var long = loc.longitude
          var lat = loc.latitude

          $("#result").load("location", function() {
            $("#result").fadeIn(function() {
              $.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/15f8bf5641489ec32f66662221933c14/" + lat + long, function(forecast) {
                consolelog(forecast);
              });
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

If you declare `lat` and `long` outside of the ajax call, it will be available to the other function, but it may *not* be loaded when `$.getJSON` is called.

Comment: I prefer your answer over others as you explained _why_ and no one else did.

Comment: This makes more sense, but it still doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var long, lat;

    //location API
    $("#myweather").load("window",function() {

        $("#location").fadeOut(function() {
           $.ajax({
               async: false,
               url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
               jsonpCallback: "callback",
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function(loc) {
                   $("#location").html(loc.city)
                   long = loc.longitude
                   lat = loc.latitude
               }        
          });
      }).fadeIn();
  });      

    $("#result").load("location", function() {
        $("#result").fadeIn(function() {
            $.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/15f8bf5641489ec32f66662221933c14/" + lat + long, function(forecast) {
                consolelog(forecast);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The variables will then be available in the whole scope of the document ready function

Comment: This doesn't return anything, as if it hasn't been pushed to the variables?

Answer (score -1):

Declare the 2 variables globally without the var

Comment: this wouldn't be the best way of doing it - plus always answer with a full explanation as to why, so people learn instead of remember how to